# How do I turn an fsPath or any absolute path into a webview resource url in VSCode API?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote

The links I need look something akin to:

`https://file%2B.vscode-resource.vscode-webview.net/d%3A/Programming/Python/Lectures/Compilers/doobedoo/Episode2.mp4`

I have paths that look like:
`D:\Programming\Python\Lectures\Compilers\doobedoo\Episode2.mp4`

The problem is, I can't just concatenate the string to look like that string, I need a way for VScode to do it for me so that it's consistent with OSes, future releases and when using WSL.

For context, I can only load resources under this content policy:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'none'; media-src %cspSource% https:; img-src %cspSource% https:; script-src 'nonce-%nonce%'; style-src %cspSource% 'unsafe-inline'; font-src  %cspSource% ;" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen this: [webview docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#Webview)

> `asWebviewUri(localResource: Uri): Uri`
>
> Convert a `uri` for the local file system to one that can be used
> inside webviews.
>
> Webviews cannot directly load resources from the workspace or local
> file system using file: uris. The `asWebviewUri` function takes a
> local file: uri and converts it into a uri that can be used inside of
> a webview to load the same resource:

```js
webview.html = `<img src="${webview.asWebviewUri(
  vscode.Uri.file('/Users/codey/workspace/cat.gif')
)}">`;
```

So try:

`yourWebview.asWebviewUri(  vscode.Uri.file('D:\Programming\Python\Lectures\Compilers\doobedoo\Episode2.mp4'));`